# flexslider slider generates space in theme

Tags: css

I have integrated flexslider in my wordpress theme,

```
<div id="home-slider" class="flexslider">
<div class="shadow-top"></div>
<ul class="slides">
<li class="flex-active-slide"
```

I need to access the flex-active-slide, how can i do it with css?
Thanks

```
<div id="menu-home">
<div class="menu-about-us-container">
<ul id="menu-about-us" class="menu">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the class

```
.flex-active-slide{
}
```

Flexslider assigns that class to each slide in sequence.

If you have more than one slider you might need to qualify that with its parent, also that class will be on the li.